# $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(y^2+x)$ is not a noetherian $\mathbb{R}$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification, modules, noetherian

I've been given the task to find whether or not $R=\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(y^2+x)$ is noetherian as a  $\mathbb{R}$-module. I've been thinking of using the usual submodule of powers of $x$ to prove that it isn't noetherian. Considering the $\mathbb{R}$-submodule generated by powers of the residue classes of $x$.

$$ S = \langle \overline{x}, \overline{x}^2,\dots,\overline{x}^n,\dots\rangle$$

$S$ can't then be finitely generated on $\mathbb{R}$ because any finite generator set won't generate $\overline{x}^n$ for some sufficiently large $n$.

I feel a bit uncomfortable working with submodules of quotient modules and it looks like the quotient is irrelevant for this question. Can I use such an argument to prove that $R$ isn't noetherian?

Comment: You know that since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, everything here is a vector space, and you just need to show that your space is infinite-dimensional? Your argument is correct, but it just sounds a little strange to talk about modules and being noetherian in this context. Your argument amounts to show that the natural map $\mathbb{R}[x]\to R$ is injective.

Comment: $\mathbb R[x,y]/(y^2+x)\cong\mathbb R[y]$, which is noetherian.

Comment: @KentaS I guess the OP meant there is a strictly increasing sequence of $\Bbb{R}$-submodules (of $\mathbb R[x,y]/(y^2+x)\cong\mathbb R[y]$) namely $V_j=\sum_{n=0}^j \Bbb{R} y^n$.

Comment: @reuns oh yes, my bad---it is a noetherian ring, but not a noetherian module.